# Como adicionar uma vírgula em cada string de um loop omitindo apenas na última string?

Tags: php, array, foreach

Tenho um *loop* que está gerando vários nomes, porem preciso que o resultado desse *loop* esteja mesclado em apenas uma string e que os nomes sejam separados por vírgulas, mas omitindo a vírgula no último nome.

Exemplo esperado:

```
Nome 1, Nome 2, Nome 3, Nome 4
```

Estou usando o seguinte *loop* para gerar as strings *nomes*.

O código:

```
$nomes = "";
foreach ($valor_array->nome as $nome) {
    $nomes .= $nome . ", ";         
}
echo $nomes;
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso sem que seja gerado uma string com uma vírgula na última palavra como `Nome 1, Nome 2, Nome 3, Nome 4,`?

Existe mais de uma maneira se se fazer isso? Quais seriam?

Comment: Como dito nas outras postagens, um `echo rtrim( $nomes, ', ' );` já dá o resultado que vc quer. Por acaso, se pegar como base minha resposta na original, é só adicionar o conceito do $separador na sua, se precisar de algo mais complexo no futuro (como vírgulas e aspas, por exemplo).

Comment: Outra saida BEM simples no seu caso é `$nomes=array(); foreach( $valor_array->nome as $nome) $nomes[] = $nome; echo implode( ', ', $nomes );` (isso supondo que sejam objetos) - provavelmente, se for array mesmo, só uma linha já basta, sem loop nenhum: `echo implode( ', ', $valor_array->nome ); `

Comment: Obrigado por _linkar_ a pergunta, não havia achado da forma que pesquisei.